# Eclipse not responding, javaw.exe causing high CPU usage

Tags: eclipse

Last night, I was working in Eclipse Juno when it stopped responding. It's been doing this ever since; if I try to modify code or run it, it will stop responding for a few seconds.

In Task Manager, it shows several instances of javaw.exe running and that my CPU is at 100%. However, seeing as my computer is still running, I doubt that is actually the case. Nonetheless, these files worry me and I don't know if they should be deleted or not.

I tried increasing the memory of the classes I'm working on ([Eclipse "javaw.exe" High CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070395/eclipse-javaw-exe-high-cpu-usage) -> [How to increase application heap size in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313393/how-to-increase-heap-size-in-eclipse)) but it didn't help.

I'm don't know to much about the inner workings of Eclipse so please bear with me.

Comment: Have you tried the old cure-all for misbehaving Windows programs: reboot?

Comment: Kinda sounds like malware (besides Eclipse, I mean). When I run Eclipse Luna for C++ dev, I see at most two instances of javaw.exe with at most a few percent (plus the jusched.exe).

Comment: What did you increase the heap size to?  How much free memory do you have before you start Eclipse?

Comment: I put in -Xmx2048m for VM arguments, as suggested in the heap size question. I'll run a scan, but I don't think I have malware.

Comment: I ran a full system scan and everything was resolved. The problems persist.

Comment: If you are developing in C/C++ and are not invested in using Eclipse, you could try SublimeText3 (with add-on packages) or Qt Creator.